# How to adjust the size of the page numbers (only) in a style file?

Tags: header-footer, fontsize, page-numbering

I have a style file, which I apply to a latex document using `usepackage`, defined in a `.sty` file, that is declared after the `documentclass` statement in the `.tex` file (using *article*).

I would like to change the size of the page numbers in the document to become larger, but set to a chosen value in the style file; regardless of the text size chosen in the 'documentclass' options chosen (set to a predefined value). The code here:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields 
\fancyfoot[C]{\huge\thepage}}
```

has been attempted without any visible change.

Is there a more direct way of accessing the size of the page number without setting an option from package fancyhdr, or if that is the only route what options are incorrect above?

**EDIT** (including MWE)

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1.1cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields 
 \fancyfoot[C]{\huge\thepage}}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\color{red}}
\subsectionfont{\color{green}}
\subsubsectionfont{\color{brown}}
```

Comment: It is not the only route. It depends on the rest of your code. You haven't provided an MWE, so it is hard to say much. Presumably, either you change the definition of `plain` later or you don't use this page style in your document. If you need to comment the second line ending, you surely need to comment the space on the third line, too. (I don't know if you need to.) Or you change the definition of `\thepage`. Or you change the definition of `\huge`. Or you override settings from an `.fd` file. Or ....

Comment: `\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}` is very common for the `plain` page style. Perhaps the document class changes it `\AtBeginDocument`... There are all sorts of things that could cause your setting to be overridden.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider adding a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)?

Comment: @Vass: You should click on the link provided to understand what is meant by a MWE. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Werner, These commands are part of a style file `mystyle.sty` and is included in the .tex document as `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mystyle}`

Comment: What does that have to do with giving (or not giving) an MWE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code changes the `plain` page style. However, it never sets that as the active page style and therefore the changes are never applied. So, use

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% Change plain page style
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields 
  \fancyfoot[C]{\huge\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}% Apply plain page style
```

to see an effect.